# PMOS misleads immediately upon power on

Tags: transistors, pmos

I have encountered some problems. When I turn off S2, my PMOS will briefly turn on. Can anyone give me any advice related to this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add a cap of 1nF in parallel to resistor R1 and confirm whether it fixes the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Under your prompt, I connected capacitors in parallel at both ends of R1, but the phenomenon did not improve. However, after connecting capacitors at both ends of R3, the phenomenon significantly improved. I am not sure whether the parallel capacitor caused changes in its loop or only played a filtering role. Sorry, my English is not good.

Comment: The results of your experiments prove what Klas-Kenny answered below. The PMOS drain-source capacitance is indeed the cause for momentary spike. The parallel capacitor across R3 purely plays a filtering role. There is no loop.

Comment: I actually built this circuit, but the actual results did not match the simulation results. After the capacitors are connected in parallel at both ends of R3, the peak still exists. Compared to circuits without capacitors, the peak recovery time becomes longer

Comment: The mismatch could be that the dV/dt on PMOS source in simulations versus actual results could be different. Is this peak really an issue because my guess is that it would last only for a few micro-seconds without the cap.

Comment: This peak is usually restored in tens of microseconds, with a maximum of 24V

Comment: Such a peak normally causes no issue. So, you can decide if you really need to fix it or live with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MOSFET doesn't turn on. It "leaks" some current through the internal drain-source capacitance.

If you replace the MOSFET with a capacitor with the same capacitance, you'll get roughly the same result.

This behavior is as far as I know pretty much impossible to fully avoid, other than to filter away the spike or by making sure power isn't switched on as fast (lowering dV/dt). Or by selecting a MOSFET with lower capacitance (which might be difficult to find for power MOSFET's).